# Split column into multiple columns with unique values in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
   Col
0  A,B,C
1  B,A,D
2  C
3  A,D,E,F
4  B,C,F
```

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col': ['A,B,C', 'B,A,D', 'C', 'A,D,E,F', 'B,C,F']})
```

which needs to be turned into:

```
   A B C D E F
0  A B C
1  A B   D
2      C
3  A     D E F
4    B C     F
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `pandas.concat`:

```
pd.concat([pd.Series((idx:=x.split(',')), index=idx)
           for x in df['Col']], axis=1).T
```

For python < 3.8:

```
pd.concat([pd.Series(val, index=val)
           for x in df['Col']
           for val in [x.split(',')]], axis=1).T
```

Output:

```
     A    B    C    D    E    F
0    A    B    C  NaN  NaN  NaN
1    A    B  NaN    D  NaN  NaN
2  NaN  NaN    C  NaN  NaN  NaN
3    A  NaN  NaN    D    E    F
4  NaN    B    C  NaN  NaN    F
```

*NB. add `fillna('')` to have empty strings for missing values*

```
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  A  B  C         
1  A  B     D      
2        C         
3  A        D  E  F
4     B  C        F
```

Comment: You may like this one too (-: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71862915/2336654

Comment: @piRSquared :facepalm: :p  have you tested how efficient it is?

Comment: On small data, yes (-:

Answer (score 5):

You could use `str.get_dummies` to get the dummy variables, then multiply with the columns:

```
tmp = df['Col'].str.get_dummies(sep=',')
out = tmp * tmp.columns
```

One-liner as suggested by @piRSquared:

```
out = df.Col.str.get_dummies(',').pipe(lambda d: d*[*d])
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  A  B  C         
1  A  B     D      
2        C         
3  A        D  E  F
4     B  C        F
```

---

**Benchmark:**

On data created by duplicating the data in the OP:

[image]

[@piRSquared's first method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71862915/17521785) using numpy methods is the fastest solution here.

---

On randomly generated DataFrames of increasing sizes:

[image]

Code to reproduce the plot:

```
import perfplot
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def enke(df):
    tmp = df['Col'].str.get_dummies(sep=',')
    return tmp * tmp.columns

def mozway(df):
    return pd.concat([pd.Series((idx:=x.split(',')), index=idx) 
                      for x in df['Col']], axis=1).T.fillna('')

def piRSquared(df):
    n = df.shape[0]
    i = np.repeat(np.arange(n), df.Col.str.count(',')+1)
    c, j = np.unique(df.Col.str.cat(sep=',').split(','), return_inverse=True)
    m = c.shape[0]
    a = np.full((n, m), '')
    a[i, j] = c[j]
    return pd.DataFrame(a, df.index, c)

def piRSquared2(df):
    n = df.shape[0]
    base = df.Col.to_numpy().astype(str)
    commas = np.char.count(base, ',')
    sepped = ','.join(base).split(',')
    i = np.repeat(np.arange(n), commas+1)
    c, j = np.unique(sepped, return_inverse=True)
    m = c.shape[0]
    a = np.full((n, m), '')
    a[i, j] = c[j]
    return pd.DataFrame(a, df.index, c)

def constructor1(n):
    df = pd.DataFrame({'Col': ['A,B,C', 'B,A,D', 'C', 'A,D,E,F', 'B,C,F']})
    return pd.concat([df]*n, ignore_index=True)

def constructor2(n):
    uc = np.array([*ascii_uppercase])
    k = [','.join(np.random.choice(uc, x, replace=False))
         for x in np.random.randint(1, 10, size=n)]
    return pd.DataFrame({'Col': k})

kernels = [enke, piRSquared, piRSquared2, mozway]
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col': ['A,B,C', 'B,A,D', 'C', 'A,D,E,F', 'B,C,F']})

perfplot.plot(
    setup=constructor1,
    kernels=kernels,
    labels=[func.__name__ for func in kernels],
    n_range=[2**k for k in range(15)],
    xlabel='len(df)',
    logx=True, 
    logy=True, 
    relative_to=0,
    equality_check=pd.DataFrame.equals)
```

Comment: golfed: `df.Col.str.get_dummies(',').pipe(lambda d: d*[*d])`

Comment: @piRSquared that's really nice :-)

Comment: I may have gone too far (-: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71862915/2336654

Answer (score 2):

### [image]

This comes from my **Project Overkill** stash of tricks.

I'll use Numpy to identify where the labels are to be dropped in the 2-d array.

```
n = df.shape[0]                                # Get number of rows
base = df.Col.to_numpy().astype(str)           # Turn `'Col'` to Numpy array
commas = np.char.count(base, ',')              # Count commas in each row
sepped = ','.join(base).split(',')             # Flat array of each element
i = np.repeat(np.arange(n), commas+1)          # Row indices for flat array

# Note that I could've used `pd.factorize` here but I actually wanted
# a sorted array of labels so `np.unique` was the way to go.
# Otherwise I'd have used `j, c = pd.factorize(sepped)`
c, j = np.unique(sepped, return_inverse=True)  # `j` col indices for flat array
                                               # `c` will be the column labels
m = c.shape[0]                                 # Get number of unique labels
a = np.full((n, m), '')                        # Default array of empty strings
a[i, j] = c[j]                                 # Use row/col indices to insert
                                               #  the column labels in right spots

pd.DataFrame(a, df.index, c)                   # Construct new dataframe

   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  A  B  C         
1  A  B     D      
2        C         
3  A        D  E  F
4     B  C        F
```

---

### Time Testing

#### The Functions

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from string import ascii_uppercase

def pir(s):
    n = s.shape[0]
    base = s.to_numpy().astype(str)
    commas = np.char.count(base, ',')
    sepped = ','.join(base).split(',')
    i = np.repeat(np.arange(n), commas+1)
    c, j = np.unique(sepped, return_inverse=True)
    m = c.shape[0]
    a = np.full((n, m), '')
    a[i, j] = c[j]
    return pd.DataFrame(a, s.index, c)

def pir2(s):
    n = s.shape[0]
    sepped = s.str.cat(sep=',').split(',')
    commas = s.str.count(',')
    i = np.repeat(np.arange(n), commas+1)
    c, j = np.unique(sepped, return_inverse=True)
    m = c.shape[0]
    a = np.full((n, m), '')
    a[i, j] = c[j]
    return pd.DataFrame(a, s.index, c)

def mozway(s):
    return pd.concat([
        pd.Series((idx:=x.split(',')), index=idx)
        for x in s
    ], axis=1).T.fillna('')

def enke(s):
    return s.str.get_dummies(',').pipe(lambda d: d*d.columns)
```

#### The test data constructor

```
def constructor(n, m):
    uc = np.array([*ascii_uppercase])
    m = min(26, m)
    k = [','.join(np.random.choice(uc, x, replace=False))
         for x in np.random.randint(1, m, size=n)]
    return pd.Series(k)
```

#### The results dataframe

```
res = pd.DataFrame(
    index=['enke', 'mozway', 'pir', 'pir2'],
    columns=[10, 30, 100, 300, 1000, 3000, 10000, 30000],
    dtype=float
)
```

#### Run the test

```
from IPython.display import clear_output

for j in res.columns:
    s = constructor(j, 10)
    for i in res.index:
        stmt = f'{i}(s)'
        setp = f'from __main__ import s, {i}'
        res.at[i, j] = timeit(stmt, setp, number=50)
        print(res)
        clear_output(True)
```

#### Show the results

```
res.T.plot(loglog=True)
```

[image]

```
res.div(res.min()).T

           enke     mozway       pir      pir2
10     8.634105  19.416376  1.000000  2.300573
30     7.626107  32.741218  1.000000  2.028423
100    5.071308  50.539772  1.000000  1.533791
300    3.475711  66.638151  1.000000  1.184982
1000   2.616885  79.032159  1.012205  1.000000
3000   2.518983  91.521389  1.094863  1.000000
10000  2.536735  98.172680  1.131758  1.000000
30000  2.603489  99.756007  1.149734  1.000000
```

Comment: I was doing a benchmark and you had changed your method. It seems your previous version is faster.

Comment: I was testing it too.  I'm pretty sure It was improved by my edits.

Comment: @enke what was the test data you ran it on?  I'd like to try it.

Comment: @enke I think you're right... but not by much.

Comment: I just used the data in OP. The overhead cost of your first seems to be large but it beats the second as you increase the data. Still faster than the other two answers on here no matter the data size though.

Comment: Yeah, rerunning my tests with both.  Thx for pointing that out.

Comment: @enke I reposted results if your interested

Comment: On random data, the gap certainly looks very small. On data in the OP, it's quite large. Incidentally, the gap between my answer and yours solutions is also smaller on the data from OP. I included my test in my post if you're interested.

Comment: That's definitely piqued my curiosity.  I'll investigate at a later date (-: